# Referencing tables in pandoc

Tags: cross-referencing, pandoc

Pandoc allows referencing images via inline Latex commands. However, it seems it does not work for tables. I'm aware of several workarounds, including manipulating a resulting TeX file manually, but is there a way, for example via inline Latex, to get pandoc to output Latex/PDF/... with automatic table references, like the following (which does not work):

```
See table \ref{example}.

----------
my  table
--- ------
a   1
b   2
----------
Table \label{example}: An example that does not work.
```

Answer (score 9):

```
See table \ref{my_table}.

Table: (table title) \label{my_table}

-----------------------
Header1 Header2 Header3
------- ------- -------
item1   item2   item3
-----------------------
```

The result of the conversion can be generated by using the [web interface of pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/try).
The LaTeX output is somewhat verbose

```
See table \ref{my_table}.

\begin{longtable}[c]{@{}lll@{}}
\caption{(table title) \label{my_table}}\tabularnewline
\toprule
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.09\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
Header1
\strut\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.09\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
Header2
\strut\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.09\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
Header3
\strut\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.09\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
Header1
\strut\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.09\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
Header2
\strut\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.09\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
Header3
\strut\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endhead
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.09\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
item1
\strut\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.09\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
item2
\strut\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.09\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
item3
\strut\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
```

Compare with the ConTeXt output:

```
See table \ref{my_table}.

\placetable{(table title) \label{my_table}}
\starttable[|lp(0.10\textwidth)|lp(0.10\textwidth)|lp(0.10\textwidth)|]
\HL
\NC Header1
\NC Header2
\NC Header3
\NC\AR
\HL
\NC item1
\NC item2
\NC item3
\NC\AR
\HL
\stoptable
```

As you can see, in both cases the "table title" is correctly marked as the caption of the generated table.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would be great if you can extend your answer, for example providing the code for real implementation.

Comment: @user44431 Would you mind to elaborate your answer?

Comment: @user44431 I hope you do not mind I added the output of Pandoc. Also, [try pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/try) is very useful for trying the conversion without installing anything.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [pandoc-tablenos](https://github.com/tomduck/pandoc-tablenos) filter.  Your example would be written

```
See table @tbl:example.

----------
my  table
--- ------
a   1
b   2
----------

Table: An example that DOES work. {#tbl:example}
```

The filter is employed using a command-line flag with `pandoc`:

```
$ pandoc example.md --filter pandoc-tablenos -o example.pdf
```

The output format is arbitary: LaTeX/pdf, html, or whatever.

Comment: this to me seems like the best answer; it matches more standard Pandoc approach to referencing figures as well